# What is the correct way to customize Icon and Text position of items in a QListView?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using C++ and Qt's (4.6) model/view framework and wondering what is the correct way to change the display of items in a `QListView` or a class derived from `QListView` from:

[image]

to:

[image]

I'm not concerned about the sort order or `Flow`, I'm interested in the best way to correctly position the text to the right of the icon.

If this can only be done by writing a custom `QStyledItemDelegate` that's totally fine, I want to rule out whether this is the correct approach or whether it's best to look at setLayout or similar, example code would help.

The example application I'm looking at is the 'interview' example from qtdemo which amongst other things displays icons and text in a `QListView`.

Answer (score 1):

In that interview demo, if you change from

```
list->setViewMode(QListView::IconMode);
```

to

```
list->setViewMode(QListView::ListMode);
```

does that give the kind of view your looking for?

Comment: No: I need to keep it as Icon view but customize the way each item is rendered using a QStyledItemDelegate

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way also.

```
void CFxDRListView::changeView(int view)
{
    setWrapping (false);

    switch(view)
    {
    case eThumbnail:
        {
            clearPropertyFlags() ;
            setViewMode(QListView::IconMode);
            setLayoutMode(QListView::Batched);
            setWrapping(true);
        }
        break;
    case eIcons:
        {
            clearPropertyFlags() ;
            setViewMode(QListView::IconMode);
            setFlow(QListView::LeftToRight);
            setLayoutMode(QListView::SinglePass);
            setWrapping(true);
            setMovement(QListView::Free);
        }
        break;
    case eList:
        {
            clearPropertyFlags() ;
            setFlow(QListView::TopToBottom);
            setViewMode(QListView::ListMode);
            setMovement(QListView::Free);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```